# display month name instead of month number in mysql

Tags: mysql, ansi-sql

Write a query to display the name of the month and the number of events scheduled in each month in the year 2013, sorted by month. Give an alias to the month name as month_name and the to the number of events scheduled as number_of_events. Name of the month must be displayed as January, February ... 
I tried the following query but its not executing:

```
select convert(varchar(10),month,date) as month_name, count(*) as number_of_events
from event where year(date)=2013 group by date order by date ;
```

table name:

```
event
```

columns :

```
id           bigint(20)    primary key
date         datetime
description  varchar(255)
invitation   varchar(255)
name         varchar(255)
organiser_id bigint(20)
```

Comment: Can't you just format the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MONTHNAME(date) - something like this:

```
select MONTHNAME(date),COUNT(*) from event where year(date)=2013 group by MONTH(date)
```